# Bounding lower triangular perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, perturbation-theory

Suppose $A\in R^{n\times n}$ is a matrix equal to sum of the Identity matrix and a lower triangular matrix $L$. Diagonal entries of $L$ are $0$.
\begin{equation}
A=I+L
\end{equation}
Define spectral norm (or the largest singular value) of a matrix $X\in R^{n\times n}$ as 
\begin{equation}
\|X\|=\sup_{\|v\|_{\ell_2}=1} \|Xv\|_{\ell_2}.
\end{equation}

Suppose $|\|A\|-1|<\epsilon$. What can I say about $\|L\|$? Is there an upper bound on $\|L\|$ in terms of $\epsilon$?

Comment: if you rearrange equation as L = A - I, could you get something out of it?

Comment: I clarified the question FYI. L is lower triangular with 0 diagonal entries. So A-I has all nonzero entries strictly below the diagonal.

Comment: your matrix is so special, write the norm defintion for A, which is a triagular matrix with diagonal 1. The off diagonal is for the norm of L.

Comment: $||M|| \ge ||M_{.,j}||$ (the $j$th column) and because $|| A_{.,j} || = 1 + || L_{.,j} ||$ you get $||L_{.,j}|| < \epsilon$ hence $||L|| < \epsilon \sqrt{n} $ (or $\sqrt{n-1}$)

Comment: Agreed that $\epsilon\sqrt{n}$ is an upper bound. I am looking for something less trivial which is hopefully independent of ambient dimension and approaches $0$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$. I mentioned the latter one since $2+\epsilon$ is another trivial bound.

Comment: Is there any extra information or conditions which are relevant to your problem? Is the lower triangular $A$ obtained through say an $LU$ factorization of a another matrix with some interesting properties which could help us. Is it necessary to work with the spectral norm or would another norm serve your final purpose equally well?

Comment: I am interested in a spectral norm bound. The desirable bound is that $\|L\|>\epsilon$ implies $|\|A\|-1|<\epsilon$. You may assume that columns and rows of $L$ are smaller than $\epsilon$ if that helps.

Comment: @ecstasyofgold: Added an answer that links to my question

Answer (score 0):

I asked a general version of this question here:[log norm inequality for lower triangular part of matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702309/upper-bound-of-norm-of-lower-triangular-part-of-matrix)

Unfortunately, I have not received a hint on how to prove it yet, but assuming the problem given in the book there is correct, I use that result.
Since $1-\epsilon \leq ||A||_2 \leq 1+\epsilon \Rightarrow ||L||_2 \leq \log_2(2 n (1+\epsilon))$. The result seems correct based on testing a few random matrices in matlab.